# Dependency error while installing cinnamon

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, cinnamon

I get the following error while installing Cinnamon using `sudo apt-get install cinnamon`:

```
Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

 cinnamon : Depends: gir1.2-muffin-3.0 but it is not going to be installed

            Depends: libgjs0-libmozjs185-1.0 but it is not installable

            Depends: libgjs0c (>= 1.34.0) but 1.32.0-1ubuntu1 is to be installed

            Depends: libgnome-desktop-3-4 (>= 3.2.0) but it is not installable

            Depends: libmuffin0 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not going to be installed

            Recommends: gnome-themes-standard but it is not going to be installed

            Recommends: gnome-session-fallback but it is not going to be installed

            Recommends: nemo but it is not going to be installed

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried everything on this:

[How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

but I am still unable to install it. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

By adding the repositories required for cinnamon in this case type this in terminal,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:merlwiz79/cinnamon-ppa
```

Then issue the should be fixed if you use 'sudo apt-get -f install (program name)' to get the missing packages. Which should work, But know to add ppa repo's use the above command. Of course replace the repository to the one you want.

Comment: It didn't work still.
Some packages could not be installed.
This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gir1.2-muffin-3.0 : Depends: libmuffin0 (>= 1.1.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if the dependencies are available on your distro's repository you can do

`sudo apt-get -f install`

This will try to install those dependencies but if the required packages are not available in the repository [which is your case] then you will have to manually download and install each dependency starting with the package which doesn't have unmet dependencies.
Packages can be downloaded from launchpad.net , packages.ubuntu.com , etc.

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867154/error-while-installing-trelby-on-ubuntu-16-10/867189#867189) post might help you understand how to resolve dependencies.
I can provide more specific answer if you provide your distro name and version.