# Error while installing Trelby on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: package-management, dependencies, wxpython

I'm trying to install Trelby on my Ubuntu 16.10, but I'm getting a dependency error for Python. How do i get past this error?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

Do the following:

1. `sudo apt-get -f install`
2. `sudo apt-get install libc6 libgcc1 libstdc++6 python python-wxversion`
3. Download and manually  install (using `sudo dpkg -i <package-name>.deb`) the following in the exact order:

   - libpng12-0
   - libgstreamer0.10-0
   - libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0
   - libwxbase2.8-0
   - libwxgtk2.8-0
   - libwxgtk-media2.8-0
   - python-wxgtk2.8
4. And finally install Trelby.

**Long answer:**

Trelby depends on the package `python-wxgtk2.8` that is not present in Ubuntu 16.10 repository.
You can download python-wxgtk2.8 package from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/python-wxgtk2.8)
Don't install it now. Package python-wxgtk2.8 depends on:

```
libc6 libgcc1 libstdc++6 libwxbase2.8-0 libwxgtk-media2.8-0 libwxgtk2.8-0 python python-wxversion
```

But these three are not available in Ubuntu 16.10 repository :

```
libwxbase2.8-0 libwxgtk2.8-0 libwxgtk-media2.8-0
```

Unfortunately, libwxgtk-media2.8-0 depends on:

```
libpng12-0 libgstreamer0.10-0 libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0
```

and these too were removed from 16.10 's repo.

Search and download the above packages from http://packages.ubuntu.com/
OR simply google with package-name followed by "ubuntu package"

So to solve your issue, first install all dependencies of pyhton-wxgtk2.8 and then install trelby.